# Intercept all outgoing mails from the OS level?

Tags: asp.net, windows, email, automation, smtp

Does anyone know of an application or approach to intercept all outgoing emails from a server and either stop them from leaving the machine or land somewhere else?

Trying to test to make sure an application is firing off automated emails successfully but don't want the sender to ever receive the email (destination SMTP server should never be hit).

I'd like to do this application agnostic (i.e. intercept all emails regardless of which application is sending it).

There have been a few similarly asked questions on SO related to Magneto and Ruby but they were too specific for what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I basically have a DEBUG_MAIL property within my application that, if set to true, will strip out any To/CC/BCC information on a to-be-sent email and replaces the To-field with a pre-set email address (my own, to be precise). It's application-specific, but the approach should work. For a Windows OS-level though...not sure.

Comment: Have you looked into using an SMTP proxy?

Comment: @ChrisForrence There are some complexities as the email "to" information isn't centralized and emails are built in multiple areas of the application. Coming into something that's designed below expectations to say the least. Thinking application agnostic to prevent me from having to chase down all these points.

Comment: @admdrew I have not. Would it have to be configured in the package sent for each email, or do you know if I could configure a proxy in one place to globally affect all emails coming from the system?

Comment: In my past experience with Linux-based routers/firewalls, we configured rules to transparently proxy all outbound SMTP traffic, which is global as it will apply to all outbound SMTP traffic, and does not require any configuration on the sending server. "transparent smtp proxy" might be a decent search to start with. It's not super trivial to setup, but it might be a good option in your environment.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks for the push in the right direction. I think this is what will work best for my scenario. I'll start looking into it.

Comment: @zacc206 I remembered that we used a [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org/) instance to do exactly what you want, but unfortunately this was at a previous employer and I do not have any access to the configuration to set this up.